# Writing and reading back from a .txt file

Tags: python, matrix

I want to write a 2D matrix to a .txt file and then read this matrix back from the .txt file. For writing, I am doing this:

```
mat = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
fout = open("file.txt", "w")
fout.write(str(mat))
fout.close()
```

This is working fine and saving the matrix to the .txt file. Later when I try to read this matrix back, it's not working for me and the following code doesn't print anything on the console:

```
mat1 = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in mat1:
    print line
```

First question, what mistake am I doing in reading the file? Secondly, after reading starts to work fine, mat1 would be a string. I want it to be an integer matrix just as original matrix mat.

Comment: Nothing prints because you used `write()` which doesn't automatically add a newline at the end of the text produced by `str(mat)`. You can fix the printing problem by using `fout.write(str(mat) + '\n')`. This however will only get you the matrix back as a string. You'll need more to get it back as a matrix as shown in some of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Using pickle module:

```
import pickle
new_list = [[1, 2],[3,4]]
fout = open("file.txt", "wb")
pickle.dump(new_list,fout)
fout.close()

mat1 = open("file.txt", "r")
old_list = pickle.load(mat1)
print old_list[1] #example
```

Comment: No, it's writing the pickle dump.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [literal_eval()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) when reading the matrix back:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the
>   following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists,
>   dicts, booleans, and None.

```
from ast import literal_eval

mat = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(str(mat))


with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    mat1 = literal_eval(f.read())

print mat1  # prints [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print type(mat1)  # prints <type 'list'>
```

Another option is to use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

```
import pickle

mat = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    pickle.dump(mat, f)

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    mat1 = pickle.load(f)

print mat1  # prints [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print type(mat1)  # prints <type 'list'>
```

Also, if speed really matters, consider using [cPickle](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/module-cPickle.html) instead of `pickle`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: For the `literal_eval` version, in general it really should be `f.write(repr(mat))` because for some types `str()` might produce different results than `repr()` does. For the `pickle` version, what's being written to the text file isn't text.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to work with matrices of numbers in Python (especially in the scientific context) are [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) arrays. Numpy provides two methods [savetxt()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt) and [loadtxt()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) to store and load these arrays. The methods also allow customize the text format.